# View questions & answers inline from any comment or post!

Tags: script, hyperlinks

[image]

This userscript adds small arrows next to links to posts on the same site. Clicking them will cause a box to be added below, containing the actual post! Just like it does in the profile 'actions' tab (and others).

### Installation

1. Install Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey
2. Install [the script](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6efa5cb9f58313c2c001/raw/86e9fe3dcec7a29052df1b316582896b3c831575/viewPostsInline.user.js) (or [view the source](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6efa5cb9f58313c2c001))

### Usage

The arrows will now be added automatically and all you have to do is click them :)

### Bugs, Feature Requests

For bugs, please check the console, and the network tab, and add anything suspicious to your report :)

For feature-requests, please post them as an answer here.

Comment: This feature is now in SOX, so please install that for this feature along with many others! :)

Comment: In SOX, it only describes adding an arrow, implying that it is simply formatting.  The ability to use the arrow to display the post is never mentioned.  That's important information, and not obvious from the feature, itself.

Comment: @fixer1234 fixed in v1.0.2dev

Comment: The feature works.  It's just not documented that the arrow does something other than look pretty (it's described as though it just adds an arrow to the underlining; i.e., link format enhancement so links, themselves, are more visible); there's no way to be aware that this feature (click arrow to display post), exists in SOX.  The problem is just that it needs better advertising.  :-)

Comment: Yeah, I changed the feature's description in SOX now